# Reference original array and double numbers PHP

Tags: php

I am getting deeper into PHP and I am attempting to double the original values of a given array in PHP.  Here is the code if it were to return a different array:

```
$blandArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

function doubleNumbers($arr) {

    $doubledArray = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 

        $doubledArray[$i] = $arr[$i] * 2;

    }

    return $doubledArray;

}

print_r(doubleNumbers($blandArray));
```

This returns the numbers doubled as expected, but in a new array.  What I want is to double the original array.  So, if `blandArray` was passed and echoed after running through the function, it would have the values doubled.  I understand that I have to use the `&` to reference that in the argument passed, but I am having no luck.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to not only pass by reference, but also *change the variable*!

```
function doubleNumbers(&$arr) {
    for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
        $arr[$i] *= 2;
    }
}
$blandArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
doubleNumbers($blandArray);
print_r($blandArray);
```

Notice also that it doesn't return any more; that would also copy the array, so we just use it out-of-line.

Comment: Hmm..  I am having no luck with this on my end.  I tried this originally as well.

Comment: @SethenMaleno Aside from missing a semicolon, this works fine. Example: http://codepad.org/NPsFzOUW

Comment: I guess where I goofed when I tried my version of this is I tried to return the array.  I guess that's not necessary.

Comment: No, returning always copies. As far as I'm aware you can't return by reference in PHP, although you've got me interested so I'm off to look it up!

Comment: Well that was quick to solve: you can http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you pass by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). This could also be achieved with [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), such as:

```
$blandArray = array_map(function($val) {
    return $val * 2;
}, $blandArray);
```

Comment: I like this solution.  Doesn't use a user defined function.

Comment: This still makes a copy of the array though, you're just assigning it back to the original variable. Whether the distinction is important is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as im aware you would beable to just overwrite the old values . . .

```
$blandArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

function doubleNumbers($arr) {

for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
$arr[i] = $arr[i] * 2;

//or

$arr[i] *= 2;

}

}
print_r(doubleNumbers($blandArray));
```

I dont think you would have to return anything either if your always doubling the array into the same array you give the function. Im giving this answer from knowledge of Actionscript, the syntax maybe different hence why iv added 2 line within the loop.